# Create Secondary User Store with LDAP in WSO2IS 5.11.0 via deployment.toml

Tags: wso2, ldap, integration, wso2-identity-server

i am trying to create a secondary user store (LDAP in this case) in WSO2IS (5.11.0) throught deployment.toml but within the wso2 documentation there isn't anything about this topic; in particular here : https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.11.0/setup/configuring-secondary-user-stores/ is described how we can create a secondary user store directly via wso2 console. Is there someone who can show me how is the configuration into deployment.toml that i have to write to allow the creation of this secondary user store not via console but via deployment.toml?

I tryed to follow this guide : https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.11.0/setup/configuring-a-read-write-ldap-user-store/#properties-used-in-read-write-ldap-user-store-manager but here you can change a primary user store from H2 to LDAP in this case, but this is not what i expected (i want to add a secondary user store not change the primary)

Comment: Adding a secondary user store can easily be done via the UI as described in the documentation, and this is the usual method.

Comment: Thanks @NilukaMonnankulama; but my wso2is instance is installed within pod in kubernetes so i need to fix this configuration necessarly inside the deployment.toml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you can do as a workaround, create a secondary userstore from the UI. This will create an XML file with the userstore configurations in the directory `<IS_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/userstores`. Use this XML as a template and maintain it as you maintain the `deployment.toml`, when the pod is created you can copy this `userstore.xml` file to the same location.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ycr
I copied the userstore.xml within this path <IS_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/userstores and when the pod started it has loaded the new secondary user store directly into the wso2. Now i can see it within the user store section into wso2 UI. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Since your instance is installed as a Kubernetes pod, you can mount a persistent volume and add the secondary user stores there. This will automatically populate the XML files to the new pods.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't add the secondary user store into a persistent volume because this second user store is an extrernal ldap and the requirement is to integrate it